# Lua: Process all permutations of text output and return alternative text

Tags: lua, permutation

I asked for help on this particular Lua code a long while ago, and it's served me well. Now I'm looking to make changes to it, and I am not sure I'm going about it the right way.

For starters, on the MUD I play, we have several flags that can prefix an equipment item. They are: `(K)`, `(M)`, `(I)`, `(G)`, and `(H)`. They will always appear in that order, regardless of which flags actually exist. For instance:

`(K)(M)(G)(H)`
`(M)(H)`
`(K)(I)(G)`

and so on. The code I have simply takes the above combinations and changes it to `KMGH`, `MH`, and `KIG`, respectively. What I'd like to do now is match on any combination of letters and return them surrounded by brackets, so `[KMGH]`, etc.

```
for i = 1, #TriggerStyleRuns do

    TSRt = TriggerStyleRuns[i].text
    if string.match(TSRt,"(K)") or string.match(TSRt,"(I)") or string.match(TSRt,"(M)") or string.match(TSRt, "(G)") or string.match(TSRt, "(H)") then
        TriggerStyleRuns[i].text = string.gsub(TSRt,"%%((%%w)%%)","%%1")
    end
end
```

Using the code above, the only way I can envision my plans happening is by looking ahead for each combination, but I really don't want to have several lines of

```
if string.match(TriggerStyleRuns[i].text, "(K)") and string.match(TriggerStyelRuns[i+1].text, "(M)" and...
```

because while I could do it, it's a lot of extra work. Is there a simpler way to process them all and make sure the first element found receives a `[` at the beginning and the last element found receives a `]`?

Added bonus: I'd like to strip out the `(I)` from it and use it to color the brackets, which requires me to table.insert prior to the first element and insert after the last element. For added reference, see the style of TriggerStyleRuns table below:

```
TriggerStyleRuns = {
  {"backcolour"=0,"text"="( 7) ", "length"=5, "style"=1, "textcolour"=16777215}, 
  {"backcolour"=0,"text"="(K)", "length"=3, "style"=1, "textcolour"=255},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="(M)", "length"=3, "style"=1, "textcolour"=16711680},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="(G)", "length"=3, "style"=1, "textcolour"=16777215},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="(H) ", "length"=4, "style"=1, "textcolour"=16776960},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="a ", "length"=2, "style"=0, "textcolour"=12632256},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="Bag of ", "length"=7, "style"=1, "textcolour"=65535},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="Aardwolf", "length"=8, "style"=1, "textcolour"=255},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"=" ", "length"=1, "style"=0, "textcolour"=12632256},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="(", "length"=1, "style"=1, "textcolour"=16777215},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="72", "length"=2, "style"=1, "textcolour"=65280},
 {"backcolour"=0, "text"=")", "length"=1, "style"=1, "textcolour"=16777215}
}
```

The number of indices can change, but I'm mostly concerned about the flags as described above.

**EDIT**
The `for` loop iterates through the `TriggerStyleRuns` table. An example is indicated above. As mentioned, the number of indices can change, and this includes the number of flags. For instance, if the (K) flag doesn't exist, in the table above, the 2nd index would instead be of (M), and not (K). So essentially, I need to iterate through the table, pulling all the flag matches, changing the text in those indices, and create a new one at the location just before the first flag and one just after. For example, the above table would look like this when it was done:

```
TriggerStyleRuns = {
  {"backcolour"=0,"text"="( 7) ", "length"=5, "style"=1, "textcolour"=16777215}, 
  {"backcolour"=0,"text"="[", "length"=1, "style"=1, "textcolour"=1234567},
  {"backcolour"=0,"text"="K","length"="1", "style"=1, "textcolour"=255}, 
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="M", "length"=3, "style"=1, "textcolour"=16711680},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="G", "length"=3, "style"=1, "textcolour"=16777215},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="H ", "length"=4, "style"=1, "textcolour"=16776960},
  {"backcolour"=0,"text"="]", "length"=1, "style"=1, "textcolour"=1234567},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="a ", "length"=2, "style"=0, "textcolour"=12632256},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="Bag of ", "length"=7, "style"=1, "textcolour"=65535},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="Aardwolf", "length"=8, "style"=1, "textcolour"=255},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"=" ", "length"=1, "style"=0, "textcolour"=12632256},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="(", "length"=1, "style"=1, "textcolour"=16777215},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"="72", "length"=2, "style"=1, "textcolour"=65280},
  {"backcolour"=0, "text"=")", "length"=1, "style"=1, "textcolour"=16777215}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really following your description, but from what I understand, what you want to do is, given an arbitrary order of those letters, return them in the specified order, surrounded by square brackets. This is one option:

```
function orderOptions( str )
    local letters = { k = '', m = '', i = '', g = '', h = '' }
    str:gsub( '%((.)%)', function( letter )
        letters[letter] = letter
    end )
    return '[' .. letters.k .. letters.m .. letters.i .. letters.g .. letters.h .. ']'
end
```

But what's wrong with, assuming they're in the right order already:

```
for i = 1, #TriggerStyleRuns do

    TSRt = TriggerStyleRuns[i].text
    if string.match(TSRt,"(K)") or string.match(TSRt,"(I)") or string.match(TSRt,"(M)") or string.match(TSRt, "(G)") or string.match(TSRt, "(H)") then
        TriggerStyleRuns[i].text = string.gsub(TSRt,"%%((%%w)%%)","%%1")
    end
    TriggerStyleRuns[i].text = '[' .. TriggerStyleRuns[i].txt .. ']'
end
```

**Edit:**

To take the text from the format of `"(K)(M)(G)"`, etc., I would do something like this:

```
-- Assuming 'flags' is the specific string
local str = '['
flags:gsub( '%((.)%)', function( flag )
    str = str .. flag
end )
str = str .. ']'
```

**Edit 2:**

After reading your updated description, I've got a much better idea of what you're going for. It still seems like the best way to do this would be beforehand, but if you're stuck doing it that way, I think I've got an idea.

Since it looks like you're modifying the table they're in (as opposed to creating a new one), it makes things a bit more complicated, but still doable.

```
local flags = { K = true, M = true, G = true, H = true }

TriggerStyleRuns = {
  {backcolour=0, text="( 7) ", length=5, style=1, textcolour=16777215}, 
  {backcolour=0, text="(K)", length=3, style=1, textcolour=255},
  {backcolour=0, text="(M)", length=3, style=1, textcolour=16711680},
  {backcolour=0, text="(G)", length=3, style=1, textcolour=16777215},
  {backcolour=0, text="(H) ", length=4, style=1, textcolour=16776960},
  {backcolour=0, text="a ", length=2, style=0, textcolour=12632256},
  {backcolour=0, text="Bag of ", length=7, style=1, textcolour=65535},
  {backcolour=0, text="Aardwolf", length=8, style=1, textcolour=255},
  {backcolour=0, text=" ", length=1, style=0, textcolour=12632256},
  {backcolour=0, text="(", length=1, style=1, textcolour=16777215},
  {backcolour=0, text="72", length=2, style=1, textcolour=65280},
  {backcolour=0, text=")", length=1, style=1, textcolour=16777215}
}

local function defaultText( str )
    return {backcolour=0,text=str, length=#str, style=1, textcolour=1234567}
end

local matchStarted -- nil
local i = 0
-- Can't use for loop because we're inserting elements into the same table
while matchStarted ~= false do
    i = i + 1
    local text = TriggerStyleRuns[i].text:match( '%((.)%)' )
    if flags[text] then
        if not matchStarted then
            matchStarted = true
            table.insert( TriggerStyleRuns, i, defaultText( '[' ) )
            i = i + 1 -- Don't want to process a letter twice
        end
        TriggerStyleRuns[i].text = text
        TriggerStyleRuns[i].length = #text
    elseif matchStarted then
        matchStarted = false
        table.insert( TriggerStyleRuns, i, defaultText( ']' ) )
    end
end
```

Comment: No, as I mentioned, no matter which flags exist, the letters will ALWAYS appear in that order. So if flags `H` and `I` are missing, it'll show `(K)(M)(G)`, whereas if they were all there, it'd show `(K)(M)(I)(G)(H)`.

Comment: @Josh Are you saying you *want* output to be like that, or do you already have output like that? If the latter, what is it that youre looking for?

Comment: The output is `(K)(M)(I)(G)(H)` (or whatever flags are actually there). What I want to happen is to take `(K)(M)(I)(G)(H)` or whatever is listed and return it as `[KMGH]` (the brackets will be colored based on I's existence).

Comment: As a side note, I think you've inadvertently have given me a better approach, at the very least.

Comment: @Josh I've updated my answer, is that what you mean?

Comment: Not quite. If you see the table in my post, the function iterates through that table. Perhaps I'm not being entirely clear as to what the function does. I'll update the post.

Comment: @Josh How about now? The example output was very helpful, now I'm not sure what you mean by the "bonus" part with `(I)`. Edited my answer. Obviously if it's possible the table may contain no flags then you would need to add a case to fail if `i` exceeded the length of the table

Comment: This, I can definitely work with. I'm going to make a small change, but this should work quite well indeed! Thank you!

Comment: No problem glad to help! FYI, in the question the table keys are wrong (quotes without brackets)